# Is there a native SQL source in Apache Flume?

Tags: sql, apache, etl, data-warehouse, flume

I need to create a simple data warehouse. The data sources for the data warehouse are heterogeneous, thus I'm experimenting with Frameworks like Apache Flume for data collection. I went through the documentation but didn't find anything about SQL. (http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html and http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-sources)

**Question:** Are there any (native) possibilities to connect an Apache Flume source to an SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this project [flume-ng-sql-source](https://github.com/keedio/flume-ng-sql-source). Here are some examples as well.

1. http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11093.streaming-oracle-database-logs-to-hdfs-with-flume
2. http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11100.streaming-mysql-table-data-to-oracle-nosql-database-with-flume

Answer (score 2):

Apache Flume is designed to collect, aggregate and move log data to HDFS.

If you are considering moving large amounts of data from a SQL database, take a look at Apache Sqoop:
http://sqoop.apache.org/